# Arch Linux ARM: Send email after successful ftp transfer

Tags: linux, email, ftp, postfix

I have a script running on my box that checks every 5 minutes to see if a certain time type was uploaded to a folder on my Ftp server. I would like for it to send an email when the transfer is successful. I've tried to set something up with postfix, but I can't find a way to put in an if statement to the ftp script, so I'm at a roadblock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have something like [`sendmail`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sendmail) correctly configured, you don't even need to have the mail command in your script. Just do something like

```
./my_ftp_script.sh && echo "FTP was succesful" | sendmail you@yourdomain.com
```

Just make sure your script exits with a non 0 value on failure.